# SQL server Backups Files types

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to read the content of my backup E.g.(testdb.bak) in a text format E.g.(Notepad or another text editor)

This command is retrieving only the file holds:

```
Restore HEADERONLY From disk = 'C:\backups\testdb.bak'
```

Is there any way or file extension, file type or format, where I can see the whole content of a backup? without restoring it.

Comment: What are you trying to see?

Comment: I am trying to see what is inside of the file (.bak) as text content. The problem is that it file in my opnion is a binary, but for example in MYSQL if you rightclick the backup and open it with notepad you are able to see the content of the backup. But I am not sure if it is possible in a SQL server backup file.

Comment: You are trying to see it as text content..... why? I believe Red Gate might have some tools. Also you can use RESTORE HEADERONLY to see some info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms178536.aspx but what are you actually trying to see?

Comment: The backup file is binary, while you may be be able to see some pieces of information inside, I don't think you will be able to see anything useful. I am now aware of any tools that can read the backup files, as it is essentially doing the same a full restore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way or file extension, file type or format, where I can see the whole content of a backup? without restoring it.

No there is no command in SQL Server which would let you see the content of `.bak` file. If you open it in notepad you would see *some* information and lots of garbage characters. This is also not supported

The best way to see its content is restore it on SQL Server database and run as many select statements you like on the tables.

Comment: Thanks @shanky, I was just trying to see what is inside according to a customer requirement. He shows me he was able to see those contents in a MySQL backup as I described above.

Comment: I don't know MySQL, but there are some third party tools which says they can read, I don't know the truth behind this. I would not waste money in buying such tools as I can easily restore and read.